# How to Read nrows From Pandas HDF Storage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, hdf5

**What am I trying to do?**

`pd.read_csv(... nrows=###)` can read the top nrows of a file. I'd like to do the same while using `pd.read_hdf(...)`.

**What is the problem?**

I am confused by the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html). `start` and `stop` look like what I need but when I try it, a `ValueError` is returned. The second thing I tried was using `nrows=10` thinking that it might be an allowable `**kwargs`. When I do, no errors are thrown but also the full dataset is returned instead of just 10 rows.

**Question**: How does one correctly read a smaller subset of rows from an HDF file? (edit: without having to read the whole thing into memory first!)

Below is my interactive session:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_hdf('storage.h5')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.read_hdf('storage.h5')
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 367, in read_hdf
    raise ValueError('key must be provided when HDF5 file '
ValueError: key must be provided when HDF5 file contains multiple datasets.
>>> import h5py
>>> f = h5py.File('storage.h5', mode='r')
>>> list(f.keys())[0]
'table'
>>> f.close()
>>> df = pd.read_hdf('storage.h5', key='table', start=0, stop=10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.read_hdf('storage.h5', key='table', start=0, stop=10)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 370, in read_hdf
    return store.select(key, auto_close=auto_close, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 740, in select
    return it.get_result()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 1447, in get_result
    results = self.func(self.start, self.stop, where)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 733, in func
    columns=columns, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 2890, in read
    return self.obj_type(BlockManager(blocks, axes))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2795, in __init__
    self._verify_integrity()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3006, in _verify_integrity
    construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4280, in construction_error
    passed, implied))
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (614, 593430), indices imply (614, 10)
>>> df = pd.read_hdf('storage.h5', key='table', nrows=10)
>>> df.shape
(593430, 614)
```

---

**Edit**:

I just attempted to use `where`:

```
mylist = list(range(30))
df = pd.read_hdf('storage.h5', key='table', where='index=mylist')
```

Received a TypeError indicating a *Fixed* format store (the default `format` value of `df.to_hdf(...)`):

```
TypeError: cannot pass a where specification when reading from a
  Fixed format store. this store must be selected in its entirety
```

**Does this mean I can't select a subset of rows if the format is Fixed format?**

Comment: i don't think `nrows` is a valid option, `read_hdf` is just ignoring it. My preferred method to handle hdf files is to use `store = pd.HDFStore(filename)` and then use something like `store['table'].iloc[:10, :]`. If I remember correctly, this won't load data into memory until you actually index the array, so only the 10 rows will be loaded.

Comment: @GergesDib That's very helpful. I'll go that route for the time being. My curiosity still remains though: how to do it with `read_hdf(...)` so I'll leave this question open.

Comment: For me `stop=10` just works as expected: reads the first 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I am pretty certain by now that https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11188 tracks this very problem. It is a ticket from 2015 and it contains a repro. Jeff Reback suggested that this is actually a bug, and he even pointed us towards a solution back in 2015. It's just that nobody built that solution yet. I might have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this now works, at least with pandas 1.0.1. Just provide `start` and `stop` arguments:

```
df = pd.read_hdf('test.h5', '/floats/trajectories', start=0, stop=5)
```